# gRPC server streaming for 1 message

Tags: java, grpc

I saw this example on the internet and was wondering, why would you use a stream to just send 1 message back? Isn't it more efficient to just return unary?

```
@Override
public void getFeature(Point request, StreamObserver<Feature> responseObserver) {
  responseObserver.onNext(checkFeature(request));
  responseObserver.onCompleted();
}

...

private Feature checkFeature(Point location) {
  for (Feature feature : features) {
    if (feature.getLocation().getLatitude() == location.getLatitude()
        && feature.getLocation().getLongitude() == location.getLongitude()) {
      return feature;
    }
  }

  // No feature was found, return an unnamed feature.
  return Feature.newBuilder().setName("").setLocation(location).build();
}
```

source: https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java/

Comment: You should state your sources, especially when you copy over code as it serves as both documentation and attribution. Which is https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java/ in this case.

Comment: sorry, forgot. I added it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all the example is there to illustrate the streaming concept. In this particular case it just so happens that it ended up sending only one message back. However the API needs to be designed for the most general case where for a given location there could be multiple Features and for some reason they cannot be combined into an array in a unary response.

Comment: In general grpc streaming can be many in one out, one in many out, many in each one returns one out thus many out but one-to-one with inputs, or ... no particular relationship between numbers in and out ... stuff comes in, other stuff goes out, over time ...

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. Ofcourse I understand that they need to provide some simple examples to show how things work. But my question is, is it more efficient to just return unary in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently I got confused between the differences of gRPC in Java and C#. I am used to developing in C#, but in Java, for Unary gRPC, they use the streamObserver object to respond. This is quite confusing...